# How to fetch all values by foreign key in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an e-commerce project. I've 3 tables here `sizes`, `products` and `product_sizes`.

`sizes` table is as follows:

```
uid | size
----------
1   | S
2   | M
3   | L
```

`product_sizes` table is as follows:

```
product_uid | size_uid
----------------------
1           | 2
1           | 3
2           | 1
2           | 2
```

What I want to do is, retrieve all the sizes by the `product_uid` which is foreign key from `products` table, this is the code I'm using,

```
    $get_sizes = "SELECT * FROM product_sizes WHERE product_uid IN($pro_id)";
    $run_sizes = mysqli_query($conn, $get_sizes);

    while($row_sizes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sizes)){

        $sizes[] = $row_sizes['size_uid'];
        $sizesAll = implode(", ", $sizes);

    }
```

For the first product I'm getting the values correctly but for the second product it combines the data.

For example if product 1 has sizes `1,3` and product 2 has `2,3` then it displays `1,3,2,3` for product 2.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `GROUP_CONCAT` here:

```
SELECT
    ps.product_uid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.size ORDER BY s.uid) sizes
FROM product_sizes ps
LEFT JOIN sizes s
    ON s.uid = ps.size_uid
GROUP BY
    ps.product_uid;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that I am not adding any PHP code, your primary question/issues seeming to resolve around the SQL itself, rather than how to consume the SQL from PHP.